# Careplan and [Careplan2,CareActivity, ....]

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have seen in FHIR CI site there is a new split of current Careplan and specially their components in several new Resources (Careplan2, CareActivity, Goal, ...)

Really, this is good because monolithic Careplan is very heavy for Careplan editors, and Careplan schedulers. We are finishing a Careplan Editor and a Careplan scheduler and really it´s heavy to keep all of this info related in a careplan or only one resource, specially for searching Careplan activities.

We will be very interested for modifying our CarePlan editors and scheduler because we could get better management.

```
My questions are:
```

- will these experimental Care plan proposals substitute the current Care plan? is there some scheduled proposal for this?

- Which group is defining this for collaborate with them?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Discussions around the scope of care plan are on-going. The alternatives you've found are definitely experimental, and I don't know what their standing is in terms of the editorial process. I do think that in the end, some kind of unpackaging is more likely than not doing it, whether it's this or not.

The work is being carried out by the patient care work group and HL7 (http://www.hl7.org/Special/committees/patientcare/index.cfm) and you should subscribe to the group email list.